# Insert data using SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am very confuse with following code .This is also inserting data into table with insert in Stored procedure, even this has not executenonquery(),executescalar() or adapter.insert like methods...
then how it is possible

```
public DataSet GetDataSet(string spName, System.Collections.Hashtable hst)
{
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 220;
    con = new SqlConnection();
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    con.ConnectionString = constr;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = spName;
    con.Open();
    if (hst != null)
        if (hst.Count > 0)
            AttachParameters(cmd, hst);
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    adapter.Fill(dataset);
    con.Close();
    return dataset;

}
```

Comment: the fill method does that internally. it executes the stored procedure defined in the command and fills it in a dataset (datatable)

Comment: Why don't you create an @Action variable in stored procedure.. You can simply pass the action="Insert/etc" you have to perform and the corresponding code will run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method just Retrieve the data u wanted and storing it into your dataset
`adapter.Fill(dataset);` this part is used to fill your dataset with the data u populate out.

So as to pass to your stored procedure so technically your stored procedure is doing the insert not this.In your stored procedure u should have a insert statement

If the stored procedure is in your database stored procedure folder u do not need to use adapter as it will run internally to retrieve the results

something like this

`INSERT INTO msdb.dbo.db(db)
        VALUES (@dbdata)`